# Firebase redirects to deleted function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am new to Firebase and is working on a project with nuxtjs, Firestore, Firebase functions, and Firebase hosting. I deployed a function that does server side rendering named 'nuxtssr' and it worked after deployment. But then I noticed that the default region of the function is in the US. I wanted to deploy the function to Europe West so I deleted the 'nuxtssr' function and deployed a new function 'nuxtssrEurope' with region set to Europe West. But after that, when I try to access my site through browser, it redirects to this page asking to verify myself.

> https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin/webreauth?service=ah&passive=true&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fappengine.google.com%2F_ah%2Fconflogin%3Fcontinue%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fus-central1-example.cloudfunctions.net%2Fnuxtssr%2F&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin

As you can see, the redirection is to the function 'nuxtssr' which I deleted which used to reside in US Central. When I verify myself, I get redirected and get this message from https://us-central1-example.cloudfunctions.net/nuxtssr/

> Error: Forbidden
>
> Your client does not have permission to get URL /nuxtssr/ from this server.

I looked around but could not find an answer. And yes I checked for any typos. This is my function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const { Nuxt } = require('nuxt')
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

const config = {
  dev: false
}

const nuxt = new Nuxt(config)

let isReady = false
const readyPromise = nuxt
  .ready()
  .then(() => {
     isReady = true
  })
 .catch(() => {
    process.exit(1)
 })

async function handleRequest(req, res) {
  if (!isReady) {
     await readyPromise
  }
res.set('Cache-Control', 'public, max-age=600, s-maxage=1200')
await nuxt.render(req, res)
}

app.get('*', handleRequest)
app.use(handleRequest)
exports.nuxtssrEurope = functions.region('europe-west1').https.onRequest(app)
```

My `firebase.json`

`{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "function": "nuxtssrEurope"
      }
    ]
  }
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently. Cloud Functions only supports serving dynamic content for Firebase hosting on us-central1 only, so you can't use other servers for Cloud Functions. After I changed back to us-central1 for my Cloud Function, it works now.

> If you are using HTTP functions to serve dynamic content for Firebase Hosting, you must use us-central1.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions